# jQuery Loop with Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery loop that is looking over radio buttons on the page and makes sure that they are checked.

The function is working but there is a glitch and I know why; just not sure how to fix it.

```
// Validate the proficiencies
var names = {};
$('.radio').filter(':radio').each(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if( undefined === names[name] ){
        names[name] = false;
    }
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        names[name] = true;
    }
});

$.each(names, function(name, val){
    if( !val ){
        theTab = 'proficienciesTab';
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + theTab + '"]').tab('show');
        $('[name="'+name+'"]').closest('tr').addClass('danger');
        $('[name=error]').empty().append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please complete all proficiencies.</div>');
        hasError = true;
    }else{
        $('[name="'+name+'"]').closest('tr').removeClass('danger');
        hasError = false;
    }
});

if(!hasError){
    //process form
}
```

The issue is in the `$.each` loop. If there are 10 radio buttons and all are left uncheck, it works fine as they all return false.

However, if I were to only check the last radio button, it will return false for all of them and then true on the last so the final `hasError` value will be true thus executing the next piece of code and processing the form.

If I just `return false` inside here `if( !val ){ }` it wont add the classes to the ones missing, it will only add it to the first one it finds false.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It'd be awesome if you could include a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `hasError = false` before the loop starts.
Then only set `hasError = true` if an error occurs.

The last good one will never overwrite the false value.

```
hasError = false;
$.each(names, function(name, val){
        if( !val ){
            theTab = 'proficienciesTab';
            $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + theTab + '"]').tab('show');
            $('[name="'+name+'"]').closest('tr').addClass('danger');
            $('[name=error]').empty().append('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please complete all proficiencies.</div>');
            hasError = true;
        }else{
            $('[name="'+name+'"]').closest('tr').removeClass('danger');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you - I had it false already by default, just had to remove the `hasError=false line`